# How to force Adobe tracking link in SMS to open Google Play Store app and not the web browser

Tags: google-play-store

I am sending a bitly in SMS that masks an Adobe tracking link to download an app. I want the link to open the Google Play app, not the web browser. Is there a way to force this? Given that I can't change the settings on everyone's phones, need to be able to do it from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of linking to play.google.com, make the link point to `market://details?id=com.example.android`, though you may find that some software will block these links for security reasons. There's no way to force a play.google.com link to open in Play Store.